# Check whether a string is a valid number

Tags: python

I need to check if a string is a valid number or not.

Here are some examples of valid:

```
1234
-1234
12.4
0.6
-0.6
-1234567890.123456789
```

Non-valid:

```
+123
123.
.6
00.6
12-.6335
```

If the first digit is a 0, a decimal point "." must come after it.

I have tried the following code but it says "time limit exceeded". I'm not sure what that means.

```
def valid_float(number_string):
    counter = 0
    if number_string[0].isdigit() or number_string[0] == "-" or number_string[0] == "0": 
        while number_string[0] == "-":
            if number_string[1].isdigit():
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
        while number_string[0].isdigit():
            if number_string[1] == "." and number_string[2].isdigit():
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
        while number_string[0] == "0":
            if number_string[1] == ".":
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
        if counter == 3:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        counter = 0
```

Comment: What **specifically** doesn't work in your code? In general, please be more specific when asking questions.

Comment: It says **Time limit exceeded** not sure what that means

Comment: Your `counter` is not going through the string. You've constructed while loops checking whether `number_string[0]` is a digit indefinitely (when it should be `number_string[counter]`), and there's no exit condition for this loop, so that's why **time limit** is **exceeded**.

Comment: Exactly. One way to change that would be to replace `number_string[0]` with `number_string[counter]` in almost all your statements

Comment: @qwert123 Please edit your question. Always include the full traceback of error messages in a question. This helps people to narrow down possible sources of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get means that the program keeps going for a long time because it is 'stuck' somewhere. Most of the time its because of a bad recursion function or, in this case, a while loop that will loop forever.

Your while loops will loop forever because you don't change the thing it checks as condition: if the condition is true in the beginning it will be true all the time so the program will never quit the while loop.

I wanted to correct your code but I can't figure out what you where trying so here is some code that will hopefully help you out:

```
for i in range(0,len(number_string)):
      if i == 0 and number_string[0] == "." :
          return false
      if i != 0 and number_string[0] == "." :
          continue
      if i == 0 and number_string[0] == "-" :
          continue
      if i == 0 and number_string[0] == "0" and len(number_string[0])>1:
           if number_string[1] != "." :
                return false
      if number_string[i].isdigit():
                continue
      return false
```